# C# program fail bec. missing using directive or an assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

the last 2 lines here are causing compiler error that 'are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference' 
where must I add this?

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using OPTFDashboard.DataModel;
  using System.IO;
  using OPTFDashboard.Common.Modules.FailedTransmissions.DataModels;

      using NHapi.Base.Parser;
      using NHapi.Base.Model;
```

Comment: All of these answers presume you're building via Visual Studio, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the assemblies that contained those namespaces. Here's a helpful link on [adding references in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Considering this is a common and basic .NET programming task, I was hoping to empower them to work out how to add references themselves.

Comment: By sending them elsewhere for the solution? Seed our own pond.

Answer (score 1):

In project explorer, find the project, find reference folder, and right click -> add reference. select the assembly and click ok.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these namespaces as project references (the DLLs).  Just because you state them in your `using` statement, doesn't mean they are automatically imported in.  You can import them through your object explorer (References).

Once you have them referenced in your project, you will be able to utilize the namespace members.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add whatever DLL has those namespaces to your project. In the solution explorer, right-click References and choose Add Reference.

Answer (score 1):

Guess. Probbably you missed a *reference* to assembly `NHapi`.

[How to add references in VS2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)